# select different hdmi-ports for video and audio on quadro p400

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

I installed kubuntu 23.04 on a box with attached display at one display port and an audio amp at another display port (both from quadro p400).
System is installed with nvidia drivers at installation and autologin enabled.

With both ports connected, system hangs after login and does not show the controlbar. System seems to be unresponsible.

When I disconnect audio amp, system comes up as desired. But now I don't have audio.

How can I configure system, that one displayport should be used for video only and another displayport(/hdmi) should be used for audio only?